# Is it ok for matured son to see mother's back during treatment

Tags: halal-haram

If a person's mother is having back pain and she request him to apply medicine and massage a little. Is it ok for the son to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if it is done by her husband or a female. However if they are not available it is also permitted for a mahram male to do it.

> عن جابر، أن أم سلمة، استأذنت رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم في الحجامة فأمر النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم أبا طيبة أن يحجمها قال: حسبت أنه قال: كان أخاها من الرضاعة، أو غلاما لم يحتلم
>
> It was narrated from Jabir that Umm Salamah asked the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) for permission for cupping, and the Prophet (ﷺ) told Abu Taibah to treat her with cupping.
>
> He said: “I think he said: ‘He was her brother through breastfeeding, or a young boy who had not reached puberty.”’
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2206)</sup>

Also note that some do not consider the back to be 'awrah with respect to mahrams. e.g. the Shafi'is only consider the 'awrah of a mahram female to be the area between the navel to the knees based on the [hadith](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4114).

Answer (score 1):

I want to add something to UmH's answer.

You can put a sheet of cloth to act as barrier between your eye and your mother's back,the same way a funeral is given bathing. Wear gloves if required.